# Upload app to App Store with out adding Apple account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to upload my app to App Store with out adding apple account in Xcode -> Preferences.

I have access to iTunes Connect and I don't have access to apple developer account but I have App Store p12 and provisional profiles.(as client has personnel apple account).

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user2931321, you need credential of developer account in Xcode,  because during build process Xcode communicates with your developer account and verify bundle identifier and others settings, so it is must for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need direct access to an Apple Developer account as you will need to add it in Xcode Preferences. This includes the Apple ID, password and device to recieve 2-Step Verification code. The `p12` file and profiles will not allow you to upload your app from Xcode. Your developer account is required for creation of profiles and certificates that Apple requires.

Can you ask your client for access?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just upload binary to AppStore and you already have all distribution certificates and provision profiles, access to iTunes Connect would be enough.

If you explicitly don't want to login via Xcode -> Preferences and this is your main problem you can submit app using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). However you will need to enter credentials for  iTunes Connect at least one time.

Comment: Thank you ..let me try fastlane

Comment: Even if you try Fastlane, you will still need your Apple account at least once.

Comment: He need access to Itunes connect for application submit, not Apple Developer Account. Apple Developer account is required for certificates/provision profiles/devices. While for app submit Itunes Connect access is enough if distribution certificates are already available.